# using javascript to show messages that php echoes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following function to show message on my HTML page, that a file was successfully uploaded. The problem is that when i upload multiple files it only shows message of the last file that has been uploaded, instead of this i want to show messages for all the files that have been uploaded. i tried something like this but didnt work.

```
    function completeHandler(event){
      var prevstatus = "";
      $id("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText + prevstatus;
      prevstatus = $id("status").innerHTML;
      $id("progressBar").value = 0;
      $id("progressBar").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
```

Doesnt seem to work using

```
   $id("status").innerHTML += event.target.responseText;
```

The function that calls completeHandler() is:

```
   function UploadFile(file){
    $id("progressBar").style.visibility = 'visible';
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    //start upload
    xhr.open("POST", $id("upload").action, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X_FILENAME" , file.name);
    xhr.send(file);

}
```

Also this function uses the div status field

```
  function progressHandler(event){
    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    $id("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
    $id("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"% uploaded... please wait";
}
```

Comment: Use the `+=` operator in `innerHTML`, it will effectively add to the string :) (obviously prevstatus won't be needed anymore)

Comment: you need to post your "file upload" code if you want constructive help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `prevstatus` is doing anything. And to append to `innerHTML` use `+=` like:

Try

```
function completeHandler(event){
      $id("status").innerHTML += event.target.responseText;
      $id("progressBar").value = 0;
      $id("progressBar").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing the `var prevstatus` everytime the function is called with an empty string.

Try to replace the innerHTML call with this one to append the new message:

```
$id("status").innerHTML += event.target.responseText;
```

or to prepend the new message you can use the following line:

```
$id("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText + $id("status").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i fixed it
i used

```
  var prevstatus = "";
```

as a global variable and the function

```
function completeHandler(event){
    $id("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText + prevstatus;
    prevstatus = $id("status").innerHTML;
    $id("progressBar").value = 0;
    $id("progressBar").style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```